# Node.JS: issue with handling multiple modules for large node application

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I am a newbie to Node.JS and began looking for best practice articles, etc. to make sure my node.js code was unit test friendly and followed the node.js best practices.  While researching I came across the following code examples:

app.js:

```
module.exports = function (flights) {
    var express = require('express');
    var routes = require('./routes')(flights);
    var path = require('path'); 
    var app = express();

    // all environments
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.set('X-Powered-By', 'Flight Tracker');
        next();
    });
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    // development only
    if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
      app.use(express.errorHandler());
    }

    app.get('/flight/:number', routes.flight);
    app.put('/flight/:number/arrived', routes.arrived);
    app.get('/list', routes.list);

    return app;
}
```

server.js:

```
var http = require('http'),
    flights = require('./data'),
    app = require('./app')(flights);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

module(index.js):

```
var Flight = function () {
    this.data = {
        number: null,
        origin: null,
        destination: null,
        departs: null,
        arrives: null,
        actualDepart: null,
        actualArrive: null
    };

    this.fill = function (info) {
        for(var prop in this.data) {
            if(this.data[prop] !== 'undefined') {
                this.data[prop] = info[prop];
            }
        }
    };

    this.triggerDepart = function () {
        this.data.actualDepart = Date.now();
    };

    this.triggerArrive = function () {
        this.data.actualArrive = Date.now();
    };

    this.getInformation = function () {
        return this.data;
    };
};

module.exports = function (info) {
    var instance = new Flight();

    instance.fill(info);

    return instance;
};
```

routes(index.js):

```
module.exports = function (flights) {
    var flight = require('../flight');

    for(var number in flights) {
        flights[number] = flight(flights[number]);
    }

    var functions = {};

    functions.flight = function(req, res){
        var number = req.param('number');

        if (typeof flights[number] === 'undefined') {
            res.status(404).json({status: 'error'});
        } else {
            res.json(flights[number].getInformation());
        }
    };

    functions.arrived = function (req, res) {
        var number = req.param('number');

        if (typeof flights[number] === 'undefined') {
            res.status(404).json({status: 'error'});
        } else {
            flights[number].triggerArrive();
            res.json({status: 'done'});
        }
    };

    functions.list = function (req, res) {
        res.render('list', {
            title: 'All Flights', 
            flights: flights});
    };

    return functions;
};
```

While I like how this is organized alot, I do not see an efficient way to handle multiple modules in this scenario.  Let's say I have additional modules for User, Initerary, etc.  This seems like it could become chaotic quickly as I began to add routes to the app.js file, not to mention how many potential parameters would need to be passed into app.js.  What if I have a large rest layer that required 20 or more modules?  I am looking for any doc or links or examples demonstrating a clean way I should do this in node.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granularize and encapsulate using sub routers with [`express.Router()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router).  Each router then becomes it's own module that you pull in making it so that you don't have to add every single route explicitly in `app.js`.

**User.js**

```
"use strict";

// Create a router
var express = require("express"),
    router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
    // All your User logic
    res.send([
        {
            name: "Bob"
        },
        {
            name: "John"
        }
    ]);
});

router.get("/:number", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send({
        name: "Bob"
    });
});

router.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
    res.send({
        name: "New Guy"
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

**App.js**

```
var app = express();
app.use("/user", require("./User"));
```

Now you can `GET` `/user`, `GET` `/user/SOME_ID`, and `POST` to `/user`.  It's also simple if you want to move the sub route around to somewhere else because the methods defined for the user route are relative.

Comment: Do you have any sample code on how this would look?

Comment: This would also allow me add User-related business logic into a separate object and access it from User.js routing file, thus giving me a way to separate concerns.

Comment: @user1790300 absolutely, it's a good way to organize for MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I too have a large enterprise app called campaign_service, consisting of many many modules.

This is how, I organize the routes in a file campaign_router.js.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var cm = require('./campaign_manager.js');
var qsc = require('./converters/qs_converter.js');
var jsc = require('./converters/json_converter.js');
var xmlc = require('./converters/xml_converter.js');
var fc = require('./converters/f_converter');
var fc2 = require('./converters/fjt2_converter');
var cv = require('./campaign_validator.js');
var templates = require('./template_list.js');
var AuthDecoder = require('authdecoder');
var adc = AuthDecoder.middleware;

router.get    ('/campaigns/qs',     qsc, adc, cv, cm.createCampaign);       // Creates a new campaign using query string params
router.post   ('/campaigns/b/xml',  xmlc, adc, cv, cm.createCampaign);      // Creates a new campaign using xml payload
router.post   ('/campaigns/file',   fc, adc, cv, cm.createCampaign);        // Creates a new campaign using uploaded file
router.post   ('/campaigns/file/type2',   fc2, adc, cv, cm.createCampaign); // Creates a new campaign using uploaded file
router.post   ('/campaigns/js',     jsc, adc,cv, cm.createCampaign);        // Creates a new bulk campaign using json payload
router.get    ('/campaigns/',       adc, cm.getCampaigns);                  // Returns  a list of bulk campaigns accessible for the invoking user.
router.get    ('/campaigns/date',   adc, cm.getCampaignsByRange);           // Returns  a list of bulk campaigns accessible for the invoking user.
router.get    ('/campaigns/b/:id',  adc, cm.getCampaign);                   // returns the details of a specific campoaign
router.put    ('/campaigns/b/id',   cm.updateCampaign);                     // Updates a specified campaign
router.delete ('/campaigns/b/:id',  cm.deleteCampaign);                     // deletes a campaign
router.post   ('/pause',            adc, cm.pauseJob);                      // Pauses an ongoing campaign
router.post   ('/resume',           adc, cm.resumeJob);                     // Resumes a paused campaign
router.post   ('/cancel',           adc,cm.cancelJob);                      // Resumes a paused campaign
//router.post   ('/reschedule',       adc,cm.rescheduleCampaign);             // Resumes a paused campaign
//router.get    ('/',                 cm.pingCampaignServer);    
router.get    ('/templates',        adc, templates.listTemplates);          // gives the campaign server templates
```

Salient points:

- All campaign functions, go into another js file (which is a middleware), called campaign_manager.js
- All payload converters go into a sub-folder called "converters", and this folder has many files called 'qs_converter.js', 'json_converter.js', ..., blah blah.
- My app performs authentication, before any campaign request is accepted, so there is a middleware loaded into the route.
- If I have other mount points apart from "/campaigns", I would create another router module and define additional .js files.
  _ I would use index.js (or app.js), to load these routers.

Essentially, it is very easy for me to scale my code into multiple modules and import them via the router file.

**EDIT** 
Added usage scenario
Index.js

```
var routes = require('./campaign_router.js');
...
app.use('/campaignservice', routes);
```

Comment: In this scenario, which file would access campaign_router.js?  I apologize for being a newbie here.

Comment: index.js.  In your case, it could be app.js or whatever the initial entry point file.